# How to style <ul> and <li> without affecting MENU

Tags: html, stylesheet

How can I apply a different styles to the same elements at different parts of my HTML/CSS.
I have tried the following it doesn't seem to work.

MENU

```
   <div class="menu">
   <ul>
         <li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

somewhere in the webpage

```
   <div class="others">
   <ul>
         <li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
     .menu ul,li{
         color: rgb(242,253,255);   
         list-style: none;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-size: 20px;
         font-family: chaparral pro;
         }

.others ul,li{
         color: rgb(242,253,255);   
         list-style: none;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-size: 10px;
         font-family: chaparral pro;
         }
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `.menu ul li` instead of `.menu ul,li` ? Same with the other one.

Answer (score 5):

The use of `,` means 'and' in CSS, so both your CSS clauses will apply to *all* `li` elements (and the last one defined takes precedence). Try simply:

```
.menu ul li{
     color: rgb(242,253,255);   
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: chaparral pro;
     }

.others ul li{
     color: rgb(242,253,255);   
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-family: chaparral pro;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a *tiny mistake* you generalized style of `li` in the following part.

```
.others ul,li { ..... }
```

The above will apply to `ul` inside `.others` and all the `li` through out the page. Just use

```
.others ul, .others li {
   /*.....*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.
Try following

However class is if you use it in many places you should use id if it is just in one place like the menu.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>


        <style>
.menu ul li{
     color: rgb(242,253,255);   
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: chaparral pro;
}

.others ul li{
     color: rgb(242,253,255);   
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-family: chaparral pro;
}



        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
  <div class="menu">
   <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="others">
   <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working.

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X6kj8/)**

Your markup is incorrect

```
<li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><Link 1</a></li>
```

Instead it should be

```
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
```

Also try to apply styles to the li element by doing something like this

```
.menu ul li
```

and not by

`.menu ul,li`